# Facebook SDK - getting access token when user logged in

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK to get users logging to my web app.

All the standard processes have been followed and done. But I'm a bit confused when it comes to retrieving an access token that will be saved to the `TABLE USERS` for the user record.

Right now I have a list of graph objects after the user logged in:

```
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Now, is there anyway I could get:

```
$graphObject->getProperty('token');
$graphObject->getProperty('secret');
```

... in order to save to the user table?

Comment: this question and the below answers don't get enough love

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is in the [Facebook\Session](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0#instance-methods) class.

So you can use `$session->getToken()` to get the current access token and then store this where ever you like.

Be aware though that they have a time limit, so when you use it again you should call the validate function to check it is still valid. Something like

```
 $session = new FacebookSession($token);
 try {
   $session->validate();
 }catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
   // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
   echo "FacebookRequestException: " . $ex->getMessage(). "<br />";
 } catch (\Exception $ex) {
  // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
  echo "Validate Exception: " . $ex->getMessage(). "<br />";
}
```

Comment: I saw people do store `secret` in the user table. Do you know what it is and why it get stored?

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: A random thread on stackoverflow but I can't remember. I thought it was something important.

Answer (score 1):

It's a first class method on the FacebookSession object:

```
$session->getToken();
```